# Chrome extension bug that could be related to cross-origin permissions

Tags: google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

We run an extension that requires fetching and searching for data on multiple websites.

We have been using cross-origin XMLHttpRequests using Jquery, and have not faced an issue until now.

The asynchronous requests are being executed successfully. This has been the case even though we have not explicitly requested cross-origin permissions as suggested here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr

This is what the relevant portions of our manifest currently look like:

```
{

"background" : {
   "scripts": ["background.js"] 
 },
"permissions" : ["storage" ],
"content_scripts" : [
    {
      "matches" : ["<all_urls>"],
      "js" : [ "jquery-2.0.0.min.js","jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js","date.js",
    "file1.js","file2.js",
    "fileN.js"],     
      "run_at" : "document_idle",
      "all_frames" : false
    },
   ],
 "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com; object-src 'self'",
  "web_accessible_resources" : [ "icona.png" , "iconb.png","iconc.png"],
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Even though the permissions do not explicitly request access to urls from which data is asynchronously fetched, the extension has worked fine.

Off late, we have had a few complaints from users that the extension no longer works and no data is being displayed. We have not been able to replicate this issue in Chrome on Linux (Version 34.0.1847.132). The users who seem to be facing this issue seem to be using Mac OS X or, less frequently, Windows.

We cannot figure out why this issue is OS specific, or if that's a curious correlation.

If the problem is indeed one of wrong permissions, can we set the permission to

```
["http://*/","https://*/"]
```

without having the extension disabled automatically for manual re-enabling by the user?

We already require permissions for all urls through `"matches" : ["<all_urls>"]`  Does this ensure that the addition of permissions as above will not trigger automatic disabling of the extension?

Comment: I left out the background details from the manifest. I edited my question to include those details.

Since there is a background page, does this mean that content scripts inherit the permissions (which apply to the background page?)

Comment: I am not sure I understand this fully. Does this mean that if the content script is being executed when visiting http://nocrossorigin.com It cannot send cross-origin requests because that *particular* site does not allow cross-origin requests.

Does this mean that the sites the extension currently works on, permit cross-origin requests?

What does "page they are running into" mean here? Sorry if the answer's obvious, but I can't wrap my head around it.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the patient explanation. So, even though chrome extensions allow for cross-origin requests, it is possible for servers to refuse these requests based on their CORS policy. Can this be changed by modifying the request header information?

Comment: Removed my comments because they were giving *very* outdated advice.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome extensions allow for cross-origin requests, but you have to declare the hosts you want to access in the `permissions` section of your manifest. The `matches` section of content scripts shouldn't give you host permissions.

You should add host permissions to your manifest. I don't know what will happen on update. Considering that the user was already prompted to allow your extension access to all their web data, maybe your extension won't be disabled on update. You can simply test that by creating a testers only extension on the webstore with your original version, install it, update it, and see what happens.

Comment: "Chrome extensions allow for cross-origin requests only from..."

Hasn't this changed with version 13?  

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/chromium/+/6d02f67b1fe41e0b8feaa3d1730d10960f1c945a/chrome/common/extensions/docs/static/xhr.html

I also know that we can send cross-origin requests from content scripts because our extension does, and it works.

Thanks for the suggestion about rolling it out to testers first.

Comment: Ups, I started developing extensions long time ago, and missed that change, so most of what I said in the comments is wrong. Answer updated after some testing. Sorry.

Comment: "There seems to be a bug with the current stable version of Chrome that allows a content script to do cross-origin requests to any host, regardless of permissions." - This seems very unlikely. Either the host needs to respond with an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, the extension needs to have declared the relevant permissions, or the `--disable-web-security` flag was used. How did you arrive at the conclusion in your second paragraph?

Comment: @RobW I had tested it yesterday, but it turns out it was an issue of Chrome not updating host permissions on extension reload. I started with an unpacked extension with all urls permission, then removed the permission from the manifest and reloaded the extension. I could still make cross-origin requests to any host from content script context.